# Expectation of a random average

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative bounded random variables and $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive constants s.t.
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i <\infty\quad\text{a.s.}
$$
Is it true that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mathsf{E}X_i\to 0\,?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Consider the following example. Let $\Omega=(0,1)$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure as probability. Let $X_i=\mathbb 1_{(0,1/i)}$. They are non-negative and bounded by $1$.

For any $\omega\in\Omega$ there exists $N=N(\omega)$ s.t. $\omega\not\in(0,\frac1i)$ for all $i>N$ and $X_i(\omega)=0$ for $i>N$. Therefore for any sequence $\{a_i\}$ of positive constants, for any $\omega\in\Omega$, only finite number of summands in the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_iX_i(\omega)$ are non-zero. So, for any $\omega\in\Omega$
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i(\omega) <\infty.
$$

Recall that this fact does not depend on $\{a_i\}$.

Now $\mathbb E[X_i]=\frac1i$ and if we take $a_i=i$ then $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mathbb E[X_i]=n$. So
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mathsf{E}X_i\to 1.
$$
Or we can take $a_i=i^2$ to get infinity as the limit.